# Existence of closed form for indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, closed-form, indefinite-integrals

During calculus studies, I tried to find a primitive for the following indefinite integral, in a simple form using standard functions:

> $\int \sqrt{\sin x} \mathrm{d}x$

I always failed. It may be possible to prove that the primitive exists, or even to find an infinite series expansion for it. But I suspect that it is not possible to find a simple closed-form expression for it.

Am I right? If so, how to prove it?

Comment: I think there is no elementary function whose derivative is your function. Elliptic functions will do it.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what functions you call "standard".  It has no elementary antiderivative, but does have one in terms of [elliptic functions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5BSin%5Bx%5D%5D%5D).

Comment: Elliptic functions are not the same as elliptic integrals, although they are related.

Answer (score 1):

Maple and Mathematica both give answers in terms of elliptic integral functions, which are not elementary functions and so probably don't qualify as "simple closed form".  A proof
that the antiderivative is not elementary would involve the Risch algorithm, but since this
is the mixed transcendental-algebraic case (which isn't even implemented in Maple) I think this would be very complicated.